# .Net: Create tagged PDF

Tags: .net, pdf, tags

I don't know much about Adobe PDF Library and Acrobat SDK. I want to create a .NET application which takes a simple PDF as input and produces a tagged PDF as output, using either Adobe PDF Library or Acrobat SDK.

Which one is the best option for me? And what are the advantages and disadvantages of both approaches?

Comment: Adobe PDF Library and Acrobat SDK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't already know exactly what byte range of a given content stream represents a paragraph or table, trying to add that information after the fact is nearly impossible given an arbitrary PDF.

If all your PDFs are from a given report from a given app, you can start cheating and bring things back into the realm of possibility, but it's still Really Hard.

Can you describe your set-up in more detail?

---

Hi back.

> First of all my main target is that how can perform tagging.

If you pick up iText in Action (2nd edition) there's a whole chapter on the subject, chapter 15.  The examples are available on line.

> No need to identify the paragraph or table at initial stage. However it is required.

Then you have a Huge Problem.  iText can give you the coordinates of all the text on the page, but it is up to you to turn those globs of coordinates & text into paragraphs.

This will probably involve tracking the current baseline and seeing when it changes by X vs changes by Y.  Any kind of fancy formatting will require special cases.  I expect you'll have a lot of special cases.  No bueno.

> But main concern is start tagging PDF. Can you provide some initial step/link to start.

Buy the book, or at the very least have a look at the online samples.

> one more thing . is it possible through .Net?

Yep.  iText and iTextSharp are virtually identical in terms of functionality these days, though that wasn't always the case.  I think they *are* identical, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Hi Mark, First of all my main target is that how can perform tagging. No need to identify the paragraph or table at initial stage. However  it is required. But main concern is start tagging PDF.   Can you provide some initial step/link to start.  one more thing . is it possible through .Net?

Answer (score 1):

Are you doing the actual tagging? Creating a PDF destroys much of the meta data so if you are not adding the tagging you would be better off crrating from the original file.

Answer (score 0):

Use Adobe PDF Library SDK - Acrobat SDK needs Adobe Acrobat to be installed on the machine. It is meant for mainly creating plugins. The PDF Library is meant for (server) applications that needs to create/manipulate PDF documents.

See this for comparision: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/pdf/library.html